# flutter and firebase and sub-collections

Tags: firebase, flutter, listview, google-cloud-firestore, collections

I've been searching high and low. Hopefully someone can help!

**firestore setup:**
usersCollection -> list of userIDs -> itemsCollection -> list of itemIDs -> item_name and etc

A lot of the examples that I was able to find, were targeting a specific userID. What I want is to load all itemIDs from all userIDs. Therefore:

- user1
- ---- item1
- ---- item2
- ---- item3
- user2
- ---- item1
- ---- item2
- etc....

I do not need it to be displayed like the above, I want to display all the items(eventually use the userID to manipulate data). Some were suggesting nested streamers but that would use a lot of power (I do not like the idea)

Then I was thinking of using some sort of 2D for loop or I also saw a for each loop. I believe these would be more suitable....

I know how to get the list of users but then I will need to get the list of items per user... how do I get that portion!? currently I am trying to display the information in a listview with tiles, but right now I just need to know how I can access the list of items.

I tried doing this.

```
List listUsers = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("users")
    .get();


for (int i = 0; i < listUsers.length; i++) {
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("users")
      .doc(listUsers[i].documentID.toString())
      .collection("items")
      .snapshots();
}
```

but we can't forget that there is a list of items too So....

```
List listUsers = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("users")
    .get();


List listItems = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("items")
        .get();



for (int i = 0; i < listUsers.length; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < listItems.length; j++) {
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("users")
      .doc(listUsers[i].documentID.toString())
      .collection("items")
      .doc(listItems[j].documentID.toString())
      .snapshots();
}
```

????????????? please help...

============== EDIT ===============================

ANSWER

```
List listItems = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collectionGroup('items')
    .get()
    .then((value) => value.docs);
```

and you access the list item and its value like this:

```
print('OMG------------ ${listItems[0].documentID.toString()}'); //document ID
print('OMG------------ ${listItems[0].data()['item_name']}'); // specific value within collection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly this looks like example of `collectionGroup` that consists of all collections with the same ID. You can check the general concept on the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

Of course there is as well Flutter implementation of this feature. You can find it [documentation on pub.dev](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FirebaseFirestore/collectionGroup.html).

Comment: winner winner! collectionGroup dinner! I edited my question to show answer.

Comment: Good that you figure it out, as I do not have any "playground" in flutter to do it. I will appreciate accepting the answer.